# Get current line of source file in D

Tags: d

Is there a way to get the current line in the source file you are on, like `__LINE__` does in C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, you can use `__LINE__`. Also, `__FILE__`.

[See Keywords section](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/lex.html)

As BCS and Jonathan M Davis point out in the comments, there is a special case for `__LINE__` and friends: when used as the default value of a template or function argument, they resolve to the *location of the caller*, not the signature of the template or function.  This is great for saving callers from having to provide this information.

```
void myAssert(T)(lazy T expression, string file = __FILE__, int line = __LINE__)
{
     if (!expression)
     {
          // Write the caller location
          writefln("Assert failure at %s:%s", file, line);
     }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I knew they didn't have to go change all the line numbers in the exception lines when they modified a std lib file :)

Comment: FWIW: `__LINE__` isn't exactly the same as in C. There is at least one corner cases where it's different: if it's used as the default value for an argument, it resolves to the line that makes the call not the line where the function is defined.

Comment: Which is *really* useful when creating test functions where you want any failures to report the line of the call rather than inside the test function.